# Outer apply (and cross apply ) against the same table result

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply, outer-apply

Considering the following script (with SQL Server 2017):

```
declare @mytable as table (n int identity(1,1), name varchar(10),mydate  date)
insert into @mytable(name,mydate) values('a','01/01/2019')

select * from @mytable t1
cross apply (select   * from t1 ) t2;

select *,mydate from @mytable t1
cross apply (select   * from t1 ) t2
```

How do you explain that

1. I'm getting 5 rows
2. Columns 1 and 2 are named c1 and c2 instead of original names in `@mytable`
3. I'm not getting mydate in script one and I am getting it only if I write it (`*` is not sufficient)
4. "this is a text" is returned in rows 2 to 5 => how do you explain that?

[image]

Comment: Where is the definition of t1 and sample data for it?

Comment: it is in the script itself: the first two lines

Comment: Ummm huh? So where do the columns c1 and c2 come from? You have a table in your database named t1 and you are confused. You can't reference a table like you are doing in your subquery.

Comment: Your query doesn't run for me. I get.. Msg 208 Level 16 State 1 Line 4
Invalid object name 't1'.

Comment: oh yes ! I got it !

Comment: I would assume that t1 has five rows in it?

Comment: yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CROSS APPLY` definition is `select * from t1` - this does not select from the alias defined above. Instead it looks for a table called `t1` and selects from it - this is in no way correlated to the rest of the query.

If you wanted to `APPLY` the values from the current row of the aliased table you would need to do

```
select * from @mytable t1
cross apply (select   t1.*  ) t2;
```

without the `FROM`.

This behaves as you were expecting.